# Why would nscd use a huge amount of RAM?

Tags: linux, debian, memory

My server seized up. It was virtually unusable. This seemed like a likely culprit:

```
root      1037  0.0 92.6 1455696 958368 ?      Ssl   2012   3:57 /usr/sbin/nscd
```

That's 92% RAM. I killed it to get my server operational again.

Given that I have now killed the process, what post-mortem diagnostics can I do to see what the cause was? `top` occasionally showed high `wa` values, which might suggest there might be something up with a file or network socket it was trying to read? Any suggestions?

Comment: Which OS and/or distro. Any relevant log entries ?

Comment: Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 . I'm not sure which logs to look in.

Comment: Start with /var/log/messages, /var/log/syslog then /var/log/* ingeneral

Comment: [Bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=549236) - You can restart `nscd` daily, or more often, if needed.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm looking for in the logs. A lot of memory-related info. Are there any particular things to look out for?

Comment: David, that seems like an answer, not a comment.  I'd certainly upvote it, if you wrote it up as one, and included some of the actual text as well as a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because it's full of memory leaks :)

The common approach is to restart the service son some regular interval or at a specified threshold (memory utilization). I usually use the [Monit utility](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to do this ([example](http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples#nscd)), but I believe nscd has a built-in provision for this as well in its configuration file.